# Should I periodically reSeed SecureRandom or it occurs automatically?

Tags: java, security, random, secure-random

We are using `SecureRandom` as follows (using `Java8`):

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
private SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
```

The algorithm being used is `NativePRNG`.

Should we seed periodically?

as it's written that NativePRNG is continuously receives entropy from the operating system (by reading from /dev/(u)random)

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.synopsys.com/blogs/software-security/proper-use-of-javas-securerandom/ suggests to reseed SecureRandom instances when "large amount of PRNG output" is generated. However, it is not specific about what counts as large amount. This likely depends on the used SecureRandom algorithm.

The Java doc does not state that reseeding will take place. If a specific algorithm supports it, you will need to explicitly specify that algorithm when calling `SecureRandom.getInstance`.

In Java 9 DRBG implementations were added ([JEP 273](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/273)) which are based on NIST.SP.800-90Ar1. This specifies that generators should reseed themself when the end of the seedlife has been reached. And you can also see that this is implemented accordingly: [`sun.security.provider.AbstractDrbg`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/security/provider/AbstractDrbg.java) (field `reseedCounter`)

However, keep in mind there is no requirement that all Java platforms need to support DRBG (though likely most will). Therefore handle the case that it is not available appropriately or include a security provider which provides a DRBG.

Answer (score -1):

Java8 doc says: SecureRandom must produce non-deterministic output.

Comment: does SecureRandom reseed itself then? do you know how?

Comment: And the same docs also say _"Many SecureRandom implementations are in the form of a pseudo-random number generator (PRNG), which means they use a deterministic algorithm to produce a pseudo-random sequence from a true random seed."_ which is confusing. Java9 adds [reseed()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#reseed--) method to SecureRandom. They don't usually tend to add something to their API if it's not considered to be an important feature.